# Is it possible to select data where date is in an array of date in mongoDB?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of object like this return to mongoDB server.

```
[{"key":"demo_date","value":["2022-12-11T08:00:00.000Z","2022-12-12T08:00:00.000Z"...]}]
```

And query object like this

```
queryObj = {
      $and: [
        { deleted: false },
        {$or: []}
      ]
};
```

And I use this query object for the find method to get data from collection.

```
let data = await this.demoModel.find(queryObj, (err: Error) => {})
```

My question is how can I modify the `queryObj` such that the result would find all data with `demo_dates` as key and the value is in value array?

The record sample are like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('574168516'),
  demoLayer1: {
      demo_date: '2022-08-18T14:20:00.000Z',
      decoyDate: '2022-08-19T14:20:00.000Z',
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be wise to use real dates instead of ISO 8601 strings.  Much better for `>` and `<` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#mongodb-query-op.-in) operator to match a value within an array of possible values:

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      //deleted: false,
      "demoLayer1.demo_date": {
        $in: [
          "2022-12-11T08:00:00.000Z",
          "2022-12-12T08:00:00.000Z",
          "2022-08-18T14:20:00.000Z"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CH-MhcMrKOT

Comment: Will the result still be normal if I use only `demo_date` instead?

Comment: No I reied to run it in demo, no document find. I wonder if I can list all fields, then use the path to do the aggregation thing to avoid using the . annotation to find inner field. What do you think?

Comment: You probably have your reasons for wanting to write the query differently, but the way it is expressed in your comment, it seems to me as trying to work _against_ the system. It also seems to me as it should be a new question, since you seem to introduce criteria that you have not initially detailed, making the issue totally different.

Comment: I just wonder if you would have the answer, but seems like not. Well I can only hope my another question get an answer than. I worked like 2 weeks to making sure client side send only an array of field and value such that I can dynamically generate the query. Like what you can do with php - sql technology :(

Comment: Yeah I think that's over engineer, since different query may have different parameter, you have to manually define what query you want for which query